# What is the minimum diameter to spin a space station to generate 1 G without affecting human vertigo

Tags: space-station, artificial-gravity

Thinking about the mars mission. If we had 2 equal weight capsules, how far apart would they need to be to generate 1 earth gravity and not affect the crew. I know from riding the round up when i was a kid, if the diameter is too small you can get vertigo. We have all see movies with circular spinning space stations to generate gravity. My question what is the smallest diameter needed to feel normal.

Comment: I think this has been asked here already. I'm trying to find the post

Comment: I'm seeing a couple of references to the 200m figure, but not the actual post I'm thinking of.

Comment: @RoryAlsop there are some good answers that address [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) induced discomfort at [Artificial gravity by centrifuge and potential nausea](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9575/12102) Somewhat related questions that also have answers that include these issues include [Would a rotating spacecraft disorient those looking out of it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/7994/12102) as well as [Why isn't a centrifuge used for astronauts on the space station?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22458/12102)

Comment: Would it also be necessary to consider rpm of the spinning object? Small diameter, high rpm would be worse than large (huge?) diameter, slow rpm, yes?